# stop opening a new tab on click mouse middle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have on anchor tag in htm. when I click mouse middle button on anchor tag then new tab is opened.
But I want to stop it's working. I tried lot of tricks in javascript but it is not working. Can anybody have solution for that?

```
<a class="tag" href="www.google.com>google</a>
```

I don't want to open a new tab by clicking with mouse middle button over anchor tag having class (tag)...
prevent mouse middle button to open new tab on anchor tab with a particular id.

Comment: what you have tried till now?

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
<a id="my" href="http://www.google.com">Clicker</a>
<div id="log"></div>
<script>
$('a').mouseup(function (e) {
   

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});


$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 2) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: `mouseup` might be too late

Comment: its working properly but it  affects on all the anchor tag in html. But i want it to work on a particular Id or class of anchor tag

Comment: Personally, unless you have a really good reason, I wouldn't do this. It's really annoying to hijack the users expected behaviour.

Comment: Don't do it, I would leave your site if middle click didn't open the page in a new tab

Comment: middle button open new tab but i don't want to open it ...

Comment: @RohanArihant Yes **you** might not want to open it, but the user does. If they middle click, they want to open a new tab. You shouldn't prevent that unless, like I said, you have a really good reason.

Comment: i agree with you but for a particular reason i want to stop it to open a new tab.. can anybody have solution                                                                          i have an working example http://js.do/rohanarihant/mousemiddle1                                             but i stopped working of all the anchor tag but i want to stop only one by it's class(my)

Comment: have you tried target="_self"?

Comment: not yet have you any working example...

Comment: also try with window.open("www.youraddress.com","_self")

Comment: this will help to stop url in new tab.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_base_target.asp 
click on try it and change _blank to _self in code

Comment: how can i use it in my code? Can you please give me proper running example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113633/discussion-between-rohanarihant-and-a-jain).

Comment: <a class="tag" href="www.google.com" target="_self">google</a>

Comment: not working bro  it will open a new tab which i don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Matt Lishman in the comments: don't.

But to give you a solution:

Your code is almost right. Only (as @GoTo says), `mouseup` is to late. 
When you listen for `click` events you can check the `which` property on the event object. The `which` is `2` when you click with the scrollwheel.

So, if `which === 2`, `preventDefault`

https://jsfiddle.net/k3o5pt6c/

Comment: i agree with you but for a particular reason i want to stop it to open a new tab.. can anybody have solution i have an working example js.do/rohanarihant/mousemiddle1 but i stopped working of all the anchor tag but i want to stop only one by it's id(my) –

Comment: Thanks for the hint that mouseup is too late, solved my hour-long googling!

Answer (score 1):

I found solution as per my requirement

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $(document).on("click", function(e){
    if($(e.target).is("#google") && e.button===1)
      e.preventDefault()
  })
})
</script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://google.com" id="google">Google</a><br> <a href="http://bing.com" id="bing">Bing</a>
</body>
</html>
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/kezcrxop/1/)